# Use a functions variable values in another function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function which allows me to browse thru files on desktop and then return a file location. I would like to use the file Location variable(strPath here) in a few more functions. How can I do that?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you
nick

```
Function FileBrowser() As String
Dim strPath As String 
Dim wb As Workbook 
strPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select your File")
If strPath = "" Then Exit Function 
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(GetFilenameFromPath(strPath))
txtboxfileLocation = strPath
End Function
```

Comment: Why not return it from the function? The code that you have doesn't return anything.

Comment: When I call this function, a window would open up for browsing a file. Calling this function wouldn't be good if I've already browsed and file and strPath value is set. using  ' Return strPath ,I'm not able to return the file location either.

Comment: VBA doesn't have the keyword `Return`. You return a value by assigning it to the function name. Any decent tutorial on VBA should explain that. Call this function once and then store the return value in a string variable.

Comment: Thank you, John. that helps. problem is now solved.                          
Thank you,  Nick